# How to pass data from Activity to Fragement in Tab layouts..?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, interface, fragment

Hello everyone i need how to passs data from activity to fragment if any easy way

**I need to implement by using Interface**

Here is the example of my data type.

```
ArrayList<PreviewData> finaldata = new ArrayList<PreviewData>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    PreviewData tempdata = new PreviewData("listname"+i+"","dsdsdsd","sdsdsdd");
    finaldata.add(tempdata);
}
```

I am using the dummy values for explaing the code in but my case values coming from web api.

Now problem is i have a activity with two tab .
**tab1** or **tab2**

when activity start then it fatch the data from server and store it on custom array list. 
**eg. finaldata** in my case

now in **tab1**  here is a list view that get the list from **finaldata**

Here is the code of onCreateView Of fragment .
i need to pass the final data values from main activity to fragment **adapterdata** list.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mydbhelper = new DBhelper(getContext());
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_all_campaign, container, false);
    ArrayList<PreviewData> adapterdata= new ArrayList<PreviewData>();
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.campaign_list_view);
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_contact_row, adapterdata);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: If custom array list in your fragment first just need to pass that arraylist to second fragment!

Comment: yes i know but how......?

Comment: Making method new instance of second fragment and use bundle for passing data with _setArguments()_ method

Comment: No need to pass .you can use static arraylist to store the data and get that in fragment..

Comment: please explain it with example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Comment: There is your example. Problem 2 -> Make `PreviewData implements Parcelable`

Answer (score 1):

Create a Constant class like below

```
public Constant{

    public static ArrayList<Previewdata> data=null;

}
```

Then assign array value to the constant class like below

```
    ArrayList<PreviewData> finaldata = new ArrayList<PreviewData>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    PreviewData tempdata = new PreviewData("listname"+i+"","dsdsdsd","sdsdsdd");
    finaldata.add(tempdata);
}   

 Constant.data=finaldata;
```

And retrive from fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mydbhelper = new DBhelper(getContext());
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_all_campaign, container, false);
    ArrayList<PreviewData> adapterdata= Constant.data;
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.campaign_list_view);
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_contact_row, adapterdata);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thnx bro i will try and rply you

Comment: i wl return  NullPointerException

Comment: Constant constant = new Constant();


@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.i("OnPostExecution","Task Done");
            
            constant.data = finaldata;
        }

Comment: Cause NullPointerException  because the data coming from server and when activity started then it's also run thee fragment itself.

but the values are null at startup

Comment: have you checked the finaldata is initialized or not..??before assign to Constant.data..

Comment: im using like this 

public class Constant {

    public static ArrayList<CampaignPreviewData> data=null;

    public static ArrayList<CampaignPreviewData> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static void setData(ArrayList<CampaignPreviewData> data) {
        Constant.data = data;
    }
}

Comment: when you what to get then  in fragment ArrayList<CampaignPreviewData> adapterdata=Constant.getData;

Comment: No need to create object of Constant class..all static variables..so can call all the variables by using class name.

Comment: And one thing no need to use set and get in constant class remove those and try only set the data.. first try to the above after than this..

Comment: yes bro every thing is working fine but the problem in when activity started it call the api and it will take time to get data and parse it according to the 

finaldata list.

but when is activity is called then the tab layout onCreateView is also created bcuz it's the part of the activity.

now in this condition there no data in final data bcuz background task is in progress.

adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_contact_row, adapterdata);
adapterdata is null  it cause the RuntimeException.

Comment: then wait till data fetched from server then show the fragment..use a progrees dialog to wait the user..

Comment: onething why you not try to get all data in frament ..instead of activity..

Comment: thnx for your valueable time  . yes im doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Please Add this code to your Activity when you call the fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
ArrayList<PreviewData> finaldata = new ArrayList<PreviewData>();
bundle.putSerializable("myArray",(Serializable)finaldata);
// set Arguments
Fragmentclass obj = new Fragmentclass();
obj.setArguments(bundle);
```

But first make your **PreviewData** like as follows(name is for example) :

```
 public class PreviewData implements Serializable{

     private String name;

    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }
   }
```

Then get your object in your fragment like :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mydbhelper = new DBhelper(getContext());
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_all_campaign, container, false);

ArrayList<PreviewData> adapterdata= new ArrayList<PreviewData>();
adapterdata = getArguments().getStringArrayList("myArray");
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.campaign_list_view);

adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_contact_row, adapterdata);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
return view; 
}
```

Comment: `putStringArrayList(String key, ArrayList<String> value)`... `finaldata` here is not an ArrayList of Strings.

Comment: PreviewData    is is alredy a  getter setter class bro so why need to make new class.....?

Comment: Ideally, you should implement `Parcelable` instead

Answer (score 0):

**In activity:**

```
public ArrayList<PreviewData> getAdapterData {
     return finaldata;
}
```

**In fragment:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<PreviewData> adapterdata = ((YourActivity) getActivity()).getAdapterData();
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_contact_row, adapterdata);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```